# Google automl_v1beta1 error "the provided location ID is not valid"

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am trying to call trained model from google colab with example provided.

But there is an error.

Who knows  is it beta error or I have not set somethoing properly?

Thanks in advance.

The code

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl

automl_client = automl.AutoMlClient()

# Create client for prediction service.
prediction_client = 
automl.PredictionServiceClient().from_service_account_json(
        'XXXXX.json')

# Get the full path of the model.
model_full_id = automl_client.model_path(
    project_id, compute_region, model_id
)

# Read the file content for prediction.
#with open(file_path, "rb") as content_file:
snippet = "fsfsf" #content_file.read()

# Set the payload by giving the content and type of the file.
payload = {"text_snippet": {"content": snippet, "mime_type": "text/plain"}}

# params is additional domain-specific parameters.
# currently there is no additional parameters supported.
params = {}
response = prediction_client.predict(model_full_id, payload, params)
print("Prediction results:")
for result in response.payload:
    print("Predicted class name: {}".format(result.display_name))
    print("Predicted class score: {}".format(result.classification.score))
```

The eror msg^

```
 InvalidArgument: 400 List of found errors: 1.Field: name; Message: The provided location ID is not valid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a region that supports AutoML beta. This works for me:

```
create_dataset("myproj-123456", "us-central1", "my_dataset_id", "en", "de")
```

Comment: I got this "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('", and  I don't know the meaning for ("en", "de") what is the meaning of that

Comment: @EnriqueZetina This is Python code. You can't directly use it in bash.

Answer (score 0):

1. I clone the repo "python-docs-samples" :

$ git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git

2. I navigate to the automl examples

$ cd /home/MY_USER/python-docs-samples/language/automl/

3. I set the environment variables for [1]:

   - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
   - PROJECT_ID
   - REGION_NAME
4. I typed:

$ python automl_natural_language_dataset.py create_dataset automltest1 False

5. I got this message:

Dataset name: projects/198768927566/locations/us-central1/datasets/TCN7889001684301386365
Dataset id: TCN7889001684301386365
Dataset display name: automltest1
Text classification dataset metadata:
        classification_type: MULTICLASS

Dataset example count: 0
Dataset create time:
        seconds: 1569367227
        nanos: 873147000

6. I set the environment variable for :

   - DATASET_ID

Please note that I got this for the step 5.

7. I typed:

python automl_natural_language_dataset.py import_data $DATASET_ID "gs://$PROJECT_ID-lcm/complaints_manual.csv"

8. I got this message:

Processing import...
Dataset imported.